# Correct Url generation flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app in which there is a template with a form. It contain 2 options and when the user submit them. It generates a url like

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/?code=L00&option=cin
```

so i get both values like this:

```
ta = request.args.get('code', "", type=str)
tb = request.args.get('option', "", type=str)
```

now after some processing on it. I generate the result. There are many results so i have pagination applied to it. The problem is how do i form the url?

```
@app.route('/search/', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/search/page/<int:page>')
def search(page):
    ta = request.args.get('code', "", type=str)
    tb = request.args.get('option', "", type=str)
    ***some processing ***
```

this won't work because `'/search/page/<int:page>'` this is not right. I need something like this 
`'/search/?code=L00&option=cin/page/<int:page>'`
Now how do i get this?
I  tried this too while testing it:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    print url_for('search',code='L00',option='cin',page=3)
```

but it generates `/searcht/page/3?code=L00&option=cin`

Comment: The search results is your resource, the page # and # of items on a page are parameters that your service should accept and return the appropriate subset of search results. This means @dragu's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make something like this ?

```
@app.route('/search'
def search():
    tp = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    ta = request.args.get('code', "", type=str)
    tb = request.args.get('option', "", type=str)
    ***some processing ***
```

page is a url param, and you just define the default as 1. Then your url_for will generate correct url like

```
/search?code=L00&option=cin&page=3
```

Comment: Yeah i did that finally as i couldn't get anything else to work. But it would have been awesome if i wouldn't have to pass page as a hidden element in the form. Anyways thank you.

Comment: @AarushiIgn I think it's the simplest way to do it. If you think the answer is right can you validate it please ? :)

Comment: The way is right no doubt. I will accept it if i don't find any other solutions.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. You shouldn't have URLs as args/options to a URL, rather identify the resources required and their parameters. Even a login interject (where you request a certain URL, but the system first has to give you a login page, and when you click logon, it has to know what page you were originally going to), should do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options here: Either define the page you want as a resource using:

```
'/search/page/<int:page>'
```

or define the page you want as another query arg, like you're doing with 'code' and 'option'. Why aren't either of those options workable for you?

Also, it'd help if you include an example of the URL that you ultimately want flask to generate... I'm not sure what you're expecting from this code:

```
'/search/?code=L00&option=cin/page/<int:page>'
```

Comment: From that code, i would be able to do pagination. I need to remember the form data for pagination. When it's `'/search/?code=L00&option=cin/page/4'` it will display the 4th page. That's all

Comment: ...but is that result a valid URL? Your URL needs to be a resource path + query string, and you seem to be wanting to tack on more resource path syntax onto the end of your query string. I don't think flask will help you create an invalid URL like that.

Comment: If the result query gives 1000 results, i can't show them on a single page.